# laravel passport createToken not giving me the hashed token

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

laravel passport createToken not giving me the hashed token.It giving me this object from database table

```
{
  "name": "Laravel Password Grant Client",
  "abilities": [
       "*"
  ],
  "tokenable_id": 10,
  "tokenable_type": "App\\Models\\User",
  "updated_at": "2021-09-02T15:58:03.000000Z",
  "created_at": "2021-09-02T15:58:03.000000Z",
  "id": 7
}.
```

I need the token for verifying.
I did `composer require laravel/passport`

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan passport:install
```

use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
in the boot  method of AuthServiceProvider
Passport::routes();
in config/auth.php

```
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
    'provider' => 'users',
],
```

my register controller function

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|confirmed|string|min:6',
]);
if ($validator->fails()) {

    return response(['errors' => $validator->errors()->all()], 422);
}
$request['password'] = Hash::make($request['password']);
$request['remember_token'] = Str::random(10);
$user =  User::create($request->toArray());
$token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;

return response(["ok" => true, "message" => "You have successfully registered", "user" => $user, "token" => $token], 200);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was just laravel was giving me sanctum by default. and the HasApiToken in the user model is bydefault coming from sanctum instead of passport.

Answer (score 12):

Please make sure you are using the correct trait

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
```

Not

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
```